# Change axis length in polar.plot?

Tags: r, plot, polar-coordinates

I want to draw a polar graph in R.

I found plotrix, which has polar.plot, but I'm open to any other solutions.

It plots a polygon just fine, even though I have a few thousand points, so great!

My question: how can I change the start value of the radial axis?  ie, how to do `ylim` in `polar.plot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using ggplot2 - it has a coord_polar() command to make polar plots

Here's the official Documentation:
http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/coord_polar.html

And a simple tutorial to work off of:
http://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/consultants-chart-in-ggplot2/

Comment: Thanks!  I'm looking for a solution in 'R'

Comment: Oh, ggplot2 is an R library in fact?  I was searching for something else, and found another reference, along with some R code using ggplot2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946630/colour-points-in-a-plot-differently-depending-on-a-vector-of-values/9948995#9948995

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for polar.plot: option `radial.lim`.