# How to color point in R with the same scale

Tags: r, colors

I have a data frame in the following form:

```
Data <- data.frame(X = sample(1:10), Y = sample(1:10))
```

I would like to color the dots obtained with

```
plot(Data$X,Data$Y)
```

using the values from another data frame:

```
      X1    X2    X3   X4    X5
1   0.57  0.40  0.64 0.07  0.57
2   0.40  0.45  0.49 0.21  0.39  
3   0.72  0.65  0.74 0.61  0.71
4   0.73  0.54  0.76 0.39  0.64
5   0.88  0.81  0.89 0.75  0.64
6   0.70  0.65  0.78 0.51  0.66
7   0.84  0.91  0.89 0.86  0.83
8  -0.07  0.39 -0.02 0.12 -0.01
9   0.82  0.83  0.84 0.81  0.79
10  0.82  0.55  0.84 0.51  0.59
```

So to have five different graphs using the five columns from the second data frame to color the dots. I manage to do this by looking here ([Colour points in a plot differently depending on a vector of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946630/colour-points-in-a-plot-differently-depending-on-a-vector-of-values)), but I'm not able to figure out how to set the same color scale for all the five different plots.

The columns in the second data frame could have different minimum and maximum so If I generate the colors using the `cut` function on the first column this will generate factors, and later colors, that are relative to this column.

Hope this is clear,

Thanks.

Comment: Collapse the data frame to a single vector, use `cut` on _that_ to build your color scale.

Answer (score 0):

You need your color ramp to include all values so you likely want to get them in the same vector. I would probably melt the data, then make the color ramp, then use the facet function in ggplot to get multiple plots. Alternately if you don't want to use ggplot you could cast the data back to multiple columns with 5 extra columns for your colors.

```
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)
Data.m <- melt(Data,id=Y)
rbPal <- colorRampPalette(c('red','blue'))
Data.m$Col <- rbPal(10)[as.numeric(cut(Data.m$value,breaks = 10))]
ggplot(Data.m, aes(value, Y,col=Col)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(variable~.)
```

Your Data object has two variables, X and Y, but then you talk about making 5 graphs, so that part is a little unclear, but I think the melt function will help getting a comprehensive color ramp and the facet_grid function may make it easier to do 5 graphs at once if that is what you want.