# R: Gradient plot on a shapefile

Tags: r, colors, plot, gradient

I currently have a shapefile of the UK and have plot the population of species in different regions of the UK. So far I have just plotted 3 levels of species population and coloured them red=high, orange=med, green=low. But what I would like to do would be to have a gradient plot instead of being bounded by just 3 colours.
So far I have a table called Count that has the regions as the column names and then the count of species for each region below. My lowest count being 0 and my highest being around 2500 and the regions in Count match with the regions in my shapefile. I have a function that determines what is high, med, low based on levels you input yourself

```
    High<-colnames(Count)[which(Count>'input value here')]
```

and then these are plotted onto the shapefile like this:

```
    plot(ukmap[(ukmap$Region %in% High),],col='red',add=T)
```

Unfortunately I can't really install any packages, I was thinking of using colorRamp, but I'm not really sure what to do?

EDIT: my data looks something like this

```
      Wales   Midlands North Scotland South East South West
 1        551       32      124        1         49         28
 3         23       99      291      152        164        107
 4          1        7       17       11         21         14
 7        192       32       12        0          1          9
 9         98       97        5        1         21          0
```

and the first column is just a number that represents the species and currently I have a function that plots the count onto a UK shapefile but based on boundaries of high, med and low. The data above is not attached to my shapefile. I then loop through for each line (species) of my data set and plot a new map for each line (species).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, here is an alternative solution that doesn't use `ggplot` (I will leave the `ggplot` solution for reference). This code is simple but it should be enough to give you some ideas as to how you can adapt it to your own data.

```
# UK shapefile found via http://www.gadm.org/download
uk.url <- "http://www.filefactory.com/file/s3dz3jt3vr/n/GBR_adm_zip"

# replace following with your working directory - no trailing slash
work.dir <- "C:/Temp/r.temp/gb_map"

# the full file path for storing file
file.loc <- paste0(work.dir, "/uk.zip")

download.file (uk.url, destfile = file.loc, mode = "wb")
unzip(file.loc, exdir = work.dir)

# open the shapefile
require(rgdal)
uk <- readOGR(work.dir, layer = "GBR_adm2")

# make some fake data to plot
uk@data$count <- round(runif(nrow(uk@data), 0, 2500), 0)
uk@data$count <- as.numeric(uk@data$count)

# and plot it
plot(uk, col = gray(uk@data$count/2500))
```

The result of the code is the following plot.

[image: screenshot]

EDIT following a request to include a legend, I have tweaked the code a little but in all honesty I don't understand base R's `legend` function well enough to get something of production quality and I have no wish to research it further. (Incidentally hat tip to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946630/colour-points-in-a-plot-differently-depending-on-a-vector-of-values) for ideas.) A look at the plot beneath the code suggests that we need to reorder the legend colours etc but I will leave that to the original poster as an exercise or to post as another question.

```
# UK shapefile found via http://www.gadm.org/download
uk.url <- "http://www.filefactory.com/file/s3dz3jt3vr/n/GBR_adm_zip"

# replace following with your working directory - no trailing slash
work.dir <- "C:/Temp/r.temp/gb_map"

# the full file path for storing file
file.loc <- paste0(work.dir, "/uk.zip")

download.file (uk.url, destfile = file.loc, mode = "wb")
unzip(file.loc, exdir = work.dir)

# open the shapefile
require(rgdal)
uk <- readOGR(work.dir, layer = "GBR_adm2")

# make some fake data to plot
uk@data$count <- as.numeric(round(runif(nrow(uk@data), 0, 2500), 0))
uk@data$bin <- cut(uk@data$count, seq(0, 2500, by = 250), 
      include.lowest = TRUE, dig.lab = 4)

# labels for the legend
lev = levels(uk@data$bin)
lev2 <- gsub("\\,", " to ", lev)
lev3 <- gsub("\\]$", "", lev2)
lev4 <- gsub("\\(|\\)", " ", lev3)
lev5 <- gsub("^\\[", " ", lev4)
my.levels <- lev5

# Create a function to generate a continuous color palette
rbPal <- colorRampPalette(c('red','blue'))
uk@data$Col <- rbPal(10)[as.numeric(cut(uk@data$count, seq(0, 2500, by = 250)))]

# Plot
plot(uk, col = uk@data$Col)
legend("topleft", fill = uk@data$Col, legend = my.levels, col = uk@data$Col)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: that's brilliant, thank you! do you know how to create a legend corresponding to this?

Answer (score 7):

All right, I'll bite. I'm not going to use base R because `plot` is too hard for me to understand, so instead we will be using `ggplot2`.

```
# UK shapefile found via http://www.gadm.org/download
uk.url <- "http://www.filefactory.com/file/s3dz3jt3vr/n/GBR_adm_zip"

# replace following with your working directory - no trailing slash
work.dir <- "C:/Temp/r.temp/gb_map"

# the full file path for storing file
file.loc <- paste0(work.dir, "/uk.zip")

download.file (uk.url, destfile = file.loc, mode = "wb")
unzip(file.loc, exdir = work.dir)

# open the shapefile
require(rgdal)
require(ggplot2)
uk <- readOGR(work.dir, layer = "GBR_adm2")

# use the NAME_2 field (representing counties) to create data frame
uk.map <- fortify(uk, region = "NAME_2")

# create fake count data...
uk.map$count <- round(runif(nrow(uk.map), 0, 2500), 0)

# quick visual check
ggplot(uk.map, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = count)) +
    geom_polygon(colour = "black", size = 0.5, aes(group = group)) +
    theme()
```

This generates the output below, which may be similar to what you need.

[image: screenshot]

Note that we don't explictly specify the gradient in this case - we just leave it up to `ggplot`. If you wish to specify those details it is possible but more involved. If you go down that route you should create another column in `uk.map` to allocate each count into one of (say) 10 bins using the `cut` function. The `uk.map` data frame looks like this:

```
> str(uk.map)
'data.frame':   427339 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ long : num  -2.05 -2.05 -2.05 -2.05 -2.05 ...
 $ lat  : num  57.2 57.2 57.2 57.2 57.2 ...
 $ order: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ hole : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ piece: Factor w/ 234 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ group: Factor w/ 1136 levels "Aberdeen.1","Aberdeenshire.1",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ id   : chr  "Aberdeen" "Aberdeen" "Aberdeen" "Aberdeen" ...
 $ count: num  1549 1375 433 427 1282 ...
>
```

Comment: thank you for your help, unfortunately as I said in my question I can't install any packages, but I'm sure this will be of use to others in a similar situation!

Comment: You have neither `ggplot2` nor the `maps` packages? Have you done a `library()` call to check?

Comment: I don't have ggplot2, I have gplots however I don't have perl installed. for drawing maps I am using maptools but yes I also have the maps package and for reading in my data from an excel spreadsheet I am using XLConnect.

Comment: I'm surprised you don't have access to `ggplot2` - it's almost an integral part of R these days. Over the long term it would be beneficial to learn and use it; I suggest you ask whoever controls your R installations to give you permission. Do `?install.packages` for details.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried colorRampPalette?

Here is how you could try to build a gradient palette

```
       gradient_color <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "red"))
       gradient_color(10)
```

[1] "#0000FF" "#1C00E2" "#3800C6" "#5500AA" "#71008D" "#8D0071" "#AA0055"
 [8] "#C60038" "#E2001C" "#FF0000"

An example plot

```
     plot(rep(1,10),col=gradient_color(10))
```

Comment: Yes I was thinking of using colorRampPalette, something along the lines of gradient_color<-colorRampPalette(c("green", "yellow", "red")) similar to how you have done it, but then I'm not sure how to apply it to my values of Count, any ideas? thanks so far!

Comment: Well, you haven't given us a reproducible question ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for details) so it's difficult to help. Having said that, putting a shapefile into a question is typically not easy to do (though you could supply a download link), but at least show us what your data looks like, then we might be able to help.