# Coloring vertexes according to their centrality

Tags: r, attributes, igraph, vertex

I am trying to change the color of the vertexes in an igraph generated graph. 
To be more specific, I have a 95 nodes graph created from an adjacency matrix and I would like to color them according to their degree/betweenness/eigenvalue centrality/closeness but I'm guessing that after I know how to do it with one, I'll be able to do it with others.

So I've coded the basics of graph generation until now:

> dataset <- read.csv("~/Google Drive/Cours M2/Network Economics/Data/Collabs_2013.csv", sep=";")
>   matrix<-as.matrix(dataset)
>   adj<-graph.adjacency(matrix)
>   plot(adj)
>   btw<-betweenness(adj,directed = FALSE)

I now have a vector of 95 values of betweennesses and I would like to plot a graph with a gradient of colors that follows the betweenness values (e.g. from red for the lowest value to green to the highest).                 I'm guessing I have to mess with vertex's attributes but I have no idea how to input the vector as a color attribute.

Comment: Pass the values to `vertex.color` eg. `plot(adj, vertex.color=rainbow(betweenness(g), start=0, end=2/6))`. See `?igraph.plotting` for more plot options

Comment: note that if you have a sequence like 1, 10, 9001 in betweenness, this will assign them 3 color equally distant from each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like you already did most of the work. All you have to know is `colorRamppalette` and setting the `vertex.color` for the network. Assuming you have to change the colors linearly,

just do

```
fine = 500 # this will adjust the resolving power.
pal = colorRampPalette(c('red','green'))

#this gives you the colors you want for every point
graphCol = pal(fine)[as.numeric(cut(btw,breaks = fine))]

# now you just need to plot it with those colors
plot(adj, vertex.color=graphCol)
```

credits to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946630/colour-points-in-a-plot-differently-depending-on-a-vector-of-values). I was using a much more inefficient method to assign the colors before answering this.

Answer (score 3):

Just a note:

It can be problematic to define

```
palette = colorRampPalette(c('blue','green'))
```

as the 'palette' function, is also used by igraph, and so igraph later produces as error.

See problem [Color pallette for vertices in igraph network in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36852821/5324967)