# Color pallette for vertices in igraph network in R

Tags: r, igraph

I'm plotting network graph in R using `igraph1. The network has 1,380 nodes and about 150k edges. Here's the summary from igraph:

```
IGRAPH UN-- 1380 159718 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), rels (v/n), label (v/n), degree (v/n), btw (v/n), color (v/c), rels (e/n)
```

I'm trying to add a color gradient that colors the nodes based on their centrality. I've tried a couple of different versions code, first from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27004167/coloring-vertexes-according-to-their-centrality):

```
# calculate betweenness
V(g_yearly)$btw <- betweenness(g_yearly)

# construct color palette
fine <- 100
palette <- colorRampPalette(c('blue','green'))

# assign palette to nodes
V(g_yearly)$color <- palette(fine) [as.numeric(cut(V(g_yearly)$btw,breaks=fine))]

# plot network 
plot.igraph(g_yearly,vertex.shape="circle",vertex.size=1,vertex.label.cex=0.6,layout=lgl(g_yearly),edge.arrow.size=0,edge.width=E(g_yearly)$rels/50)
```

I get the following error and traceback:

```
Error in seq.int(0, 1, length.out = n) : 
  'length.out' must be a non-negative number 
  9 .approxfun(x, y, v, method, yleft, yright, f) 
  8 palette[[1L]](x) 
  7 cbind(palette[[1L]](x), palette[[2L]](x), palette[[3L]](x), if (alpha) palette[[4L]](x)) 
  6 pmin(rgb, 1) 
  5 pmax(pmin(rgb, 1), 0) 
  4 roundcolor(cbind(palette[[1L]](x), palette[[2L]](x), palette[[3L]](x), 
if (alpha) palette[[4L]](x))) 
  3 ramp(seq.int(0, 1, length.out = n)) 
  2 palette(palette) 
  1 plot.igraph(g_yearly, vertex.shape = "circle", vertex.size = 1, 
vertex.label.cex = 0.6, layout = layout.lgl(g_yearly), edge.arrow.size = 0, 
edge.width = E(g_yearly)$rels/50) 

In addition: Warning message:
In .approxfun(x, y, v, method, yleft, yright, f) :
NAs introduced by coercion
```

If I use the `rainbow` function instead, this works just fine:

```
V(g_yearly)$color <- rainbow(V(g_yearly)$btw,start=3/6,end=4/6)
```

Oddly, after I've run the first bit of code once, I can't seem to run plot on the network without getting the same error -- even if I remove the calls to `palette`.

What am I doing wrong with `palette`?

Comment: How did you get a traceback?!?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issues but found the problem. When you do

```
palette <- colorRampPalette(c('blue','green'))
```

you redefine the 'palette' function, and so igraph later produces as error (I assume igraph uses 'palette' in one or the other way.

This also explains why the error remains when

```
palette <- colorRampPalette(c('blue','green'))
```

has been done once.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problems is in this line:

```
# assign palette to nodes
V(g_yearly)$color <- palette(fine [as.numeric(cut(V(g_yearly)$btw,breaks=fine))]
```

The argument to `palette` should be single integer and `fine` is a vector of length 1 so attempting to index it with anything other than `1` will fail. Try:

```
V(g_yearly)$color <- palette(fine)[ as.numeric( cut(V(g_yearly)$btw, breaks=fine)]
```

(Untested in the absence of a reproducible example.)

Comment: Well, that's an unfortunate typo, but I think it was in my post only. Regardless, I double-checked and same result.

Comment: There's code but no data at the link you are calling an "example". So it's not really .... an example.

Comment: I'll see if I can share a slice of data. It's part of a joint research project, the data is mine, but I can't share in entirety.

Answer (score -1):

In error traceback you have line: 2 palette(palette).
I think, that you overwrite variable, try: **pale** <- colorRampPalette(c('blue','green'))