# R: Colour points on a map based on their value and add legend

Tags: r, plot, colors, maps

I have a dataset containing longitude, latitude and a value column showing humidity, about 300 rows in length. Each point shows the humidity for a different location. I would like to plot all of them on a map and colour them according to their value (such as in gradient colours) and add a legend. It is a bit similar to the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946630/colour-points-in-a-plot-differently-depending-on-a-vector-of-values), but I can't get it to work. The code is basically there but only the colouring and displaying it properly in a legend does not really work. The points represent a line in Africa and the humidity values have been originally extracted from a raster dataset and they contain several digits. I created some sample data to illustrate where I am stuck.

```
library("maps")
library("raster")

# create sample data
lon <- seq(from=35.6, to=43.2, by=0.2)
lat <- seq(from=10.5, to=22.2, by=0.2)
humidity <- runif(59, min=9.6, max=13.5)
data <- data.frame(lon,lat, humidity)

colfunc<-colorRampPalette(c("dodgerblue2","khaki","orangered")) # create colours
map('world', xlim = c(20, 80), ylim = c(5, 30), lwd=0.5, col = "grey95", fill = T, interior = FALSE)
title("specific humidity along line")
map.axes()
points(data$lon, data$lat, cex=.5, pch=19, col=colfunc(100))
legend("topleft",title="q (g/kg)",legend=c(11,11.5,12,12.5,13),col =colfunc(100), pch=20)
```

The resulting plot looks like this: [image]
Something is clearly wrong with the legend, I would like to have a few points shown in the legend with the corresponding colour and value or even use a nice colourbar. I am not sure why the colour in the legend is just blue. I also suspect that the line of points is not coloured according to their actual value and just displaying the whole colour gradient. Thanks for any suggestions!
**UPDATE with code from Alex:**

```
n <- 10

colfunc<-colorRampPalette(c("dodgerblue2","khaki","orangered")) # create colours
mycol <- function(x, myrange, n=10) round( 1+(x-myrange[1])/diff(myrange) * (n-1))
map('world', xlim = c(20, 80), ylim = c(5, 30), lwd=0.5, col = "grey95", fill = T, interior = FALSE)
title("specific humidity along line")
map.axes()
points(data$lon, data$lat, cex=.5, pch=19, col=colfunc(n)[mycol(humidity, range(humidity), n)])
mylist <- c(10,11,11.5,12,12.5,13)
legend("topleft",title="q (g/kg)",legend=mylist,col = colfunc(n)[mycol(mylist,range(humidity), n)], pch=20)
```

That generates this plot: [image]
Points are overlapping and it is hard to see the overall values of the points, is there any way to colour the points according to a defined range using the colourramp? Such as "red" for values 10 to 11, "green" for 11 to 12 and so on?

Comment: Your code should generate some example data. I do not want to download a file, and in the future it will be gone, making the Q and A much less useful.

Comment: You are right, I just changed it accordingly and added sample data. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You may have mixed up a few things. In you code, you are plotting points with a colour that is only a result of the order of the points (first point gets first colour in the list etc). The colour doesn't depend on the value.

Now in a colour gradient for humidity values in the full range 0:100 you will, frankly, not see any difference between values 11 and 13. You need a lot more contrast. 
So you should first do

```
mycol <- function(x, myrange, n=100) round( 1+(x-myrange[1])/diff(myrange) * (n-1))
```

now `mycol(x, range(humidity), n)` will return an integer that is 1 for the minimum value and n for the maximum.

```
n=100
points(data$lon, data$lat, cex=.5, pch=19, col=colfunc(n)[mycol(humidity, range(humidity), n)])

mylist <- c(11,11.5,12,12.5,13)
legend("topleft",title="q (g/kg)",legend=mylist,col = colfunc(n)[mycol(mylist,range(humidity), n)], pch=20)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help Alex. I tried using your code and it works perfectly! The humidity values do not represent relative humidity in range from 0 to 100 (%) but specific humidity, therefore I change n=100 to n=10, but I am unsure if that value makes sense, as the specific humidity values are in a range of about 10 to 13.2 g/kg? Unfortunately, the coloured points really cover each other, is there a way I could assign a specific colour to the range 10 to 11, 11 to 12 and so on? In that case the line would look smoother on the map.

Comment: Any value of n makes as much sense as another, as it is just the number of different colours in your palette. For "pretty" intervals, you can use the same mycol function but set a different range e.g. c(10,14) with n=4.

Answer (score 1):

you can seq the legend

```
library("maps")
library("raster")


n <- 4 # number in legend
# create sample data
lon <- seq(from=35.6, to=43.2, by=0.2)
lat <- seq(from=10.5, to=22.2, by=0.2)
humidity <- runif(39, min=9.6, max=20)
data <- data.frame(lon,lat[1:39], humidity)

    colfunc<-colorRampPalette(c("dodgerblue2","khaki","orangered")) # create colours
    map('world', xlim = c(20, 80), ylim = c(5, 30), lwd=0.5, col = "grey95", fill = T, interior = FALSE)
title("specific humidity along line")
map.axes()
points(data$lon, data$lat, cex=.5,pch=18, col=colfunc(nrow(data)))
legend("topleft",title="q (g/kg)",legend=round(seq(min(humidity),max(humidity),length.out = n),0),col =colfunc(n), pch=20)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your example code, it looks straightforward and works fine. However, as Alex pointed out, the colours do not represent the actual humidity values.