# Independent data and group colors in different layers

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I plot the following:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=mtcars, mapping=aes(x=mpg, y=wt, col=factor(cyl)))
```

I get this plot:
[image]

Now I want to add different data with different groups and colors

```
library(ggplot2)

data = data.frame(x = rep(12, times=50), y = seq(1, 5, length.out = 50), c = c(rep(1, times=10),
                                                                               rep(2, times=10),
                                                                               rep(3, times=10),
                                                                               rep(4, times=10),
                                                                               rep(5, times=10)))

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=mtcars, mapping=aes(x=mpg, y=wt, col=factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point(data=data, aes(x=x, y=y, col=factor(c)), inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

But I get this plot where the colors of the first layer changed. How can I color the second layer after the c variable, without changing the first layer?
[image]

Comment: I don't find 'the best' answer right now, but google "consistent color between plots ggplot" and you get the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot map a single aesthetic (in this case, color) to two different sets of values in the same plot. **ggplot** is interpreting your commands in the only valid way: constructing a single color scale that includes all the unique values in `mtcars$cyl` and `data$c`.

We could, however, get close to what you want by mapping color to one set of values and fill to another. We can use `pch = 21`, since this point style has both a color and a fill. We turn off the point stroke (color) in one layer and the point fill in the other:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=mtcars, mapping=aes(x=mpg, y=wt, col=factor(cyl)), pch = 21) +
  geom_point(data=data, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=factor(c)), pch = 21, color = '#00000000')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

However, we have options with `plot()` of base R. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9946970/6574038) we can define color palettes fitting for our data:

```
rbPal1 <- colorRampPalette(c('red','blue'))
rbPal2 <- colorRampPalette(c('green', 'purple','orange'))
mtcars$cyl.col <- rbPal1(8)[mtcars$cyl]  # for mtcars
data$c.col <- rbPal2(5)[data$c]  # for your data
```

Then we can plot it by referencing to those colors, even with a legend.

```
with(mtcars, plot(mpg, wt, col=cyl.col, pch=16))
with(data, points(y ~ x, col=c.col, pch=16))
legend("topright", as.character(unique(mtcars$cyl)), title="cyl",
       col=unique(mtcars$cyl.col), lty=0, lwd = 2, pch=16)
legend("bottomright", as.character(unique(data$c)), title="c",
        col=unique(data$c.col), lty=0, lwd = 2, pch=16)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's a valid solution. Sadly I can only accept one answer.

Comment: @Benni No worries, you explicitly asked for ggplot, I just wanted to show, that in R plotting isn't just `ggplot()`.